# Chevrolet Aveo 2013 T300 won't start

Tags: starting, chevrolet, oil-change, aveo

I need some advice. After changing the oil filter, the car does not start. The starter works, the engine is trying to catch, but runs irregularly and then it stops. Could you advise me what the problem is? The oil in the car is new and optimal volume as well. Candles are new and OK. I have a fault code 128 in the info panel, but I don't know if it has anything to do with it, it has something to do with cooling: https://www.700r4transmissionhq.com/p0128-chevy-aveo/

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "drips awhile"?

Comment: Sorry, a typo. I mean that it stops after a while. Corrected.